# How to draw a scheme in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I was trying to use LaTeX to build a figure to attach on my LaTeX document unfortunately  it loses a lot of quality and I wanna to keep LaTeX style so much, so I started to build it. The scheme is pretty simple although I have too much space between lines. My biggest problem is how to write and draw the arrows on the right side. I will let here the equations as the down arrows  which are part of the code.

[image: Scheme]

```
 \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
$Construct $ v(r_i)&=-\sum_{\alpha}\frac{Z_\alpha}{r_{i\alpha}} \nonumber
  \label{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Big\downarrow$
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
$Guess $ n(r) \nonumber
  \label{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Big\downarrow$
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
v_{s}=v(r)+\int\frac{n(r')}{|r-r'|}dr'+v_{xc}(r) \nonumber
  \label{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Big\downarrow$
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2+v+v_H+v_{xc}]\psi_i=\epsilon\psi_i \nonumber
  \label{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Big\downarrow$
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
n(r)=\sum_i^N|\psi_i|^2 \nonumber
  \label{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
$\Big\downarrow$
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textcolor{green}{\textbf{YES}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: you should never use `$` in math display environments, these code fragments would generate lots of errors

Comment: @DavidCarlisle only did that to add space between the text and the equation I know I could used \hspace{} instead

Comment: no they generate errors and make the expressions unusable

Comment: Was I the only person expecting [Mumford’s map of Spec Z|x|](https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2011/05/25/a-latex-version-of-mumfords-impression-of-spec-zx-or-some-tikz-tricks/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic Ti*k*Z tools that can be used here, `chains` or a `matrix`. Here is a proposal based on `chains`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,chains}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arj/.style={semithick,-Stealth[bend]}]
\path[start chain=D going below,nodes={on chain,join=by arj,align=center}]
 node{Construct $\displaystyle v(r_i)=-\sum_{\alpha}\frac{Z_\alpha}{r_{i\alpha}}$}
 node{Guess $\displaystyle  n(r)$}
 node[alias=calc1]{Calculate $\displaystyle v_{s}=v(r)+\int\frac{n(r')}{|r-r'|}\diff r'+v_{xc}(r)$}
 node[alias=solve]{Solve the Kohn--Sham equation\\
 $\displaystyle \left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2+v+v_H+v_{xc}\right]\psi_i=\varepsilon\psi_i$}
 node[alias=calc2]{Calculate new $\displaystyle  n(r)=\sum_i^N|\psi_i|^2$}
 node[alias=q]{Does the calculation converge?}
 node[text=green!70!black]{YES}
 node{Calculate eigenvalues.};
 \path node[right=8em of calc2,text=red] (NO) {NO}
  (NO|-solve) node (gen) {Generate new $n(r)$};
 \draw[arj] (q) to[out=0,in=-90]  (NO);
 \draw[arj] (NO) to  (gen);
 \draw[arj] (gen) to[out=90,in=0]  (calc1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A way with `pstricks`: in a standard `alignat` environment, I nest two `gathered` environments, and define inside these environments  two pairs of  nodes that I connect with `\nccurve`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \begin{gathered}
\text{Construct\enspace} v(r_i)=-\smash[b]{\sum_{\alpha}\frac{Z_\alpha}{r_{i\alpha}}} \\
\Big\downarrow \\
\text{Guess\enspace} n(r)\\
\Big\downarrow \\
\text{Calculate\enspace} v_{s}=v(r)+\int\frac{n(r')}{|r-r'|}dr'+v_{xc}(r) \pnode[2em, 0pt]{Int}\\
\Big\downarrow \\
\Centerstack[l]{Solve the Kohn-\\Sham equation}\enspace\Bigl [-\mfrac{1}{2}\nabla^2+v+v_H+v_{xc}\Bigr]\psi_i=\epsilon\psi_i \\
\Big\downarrow \\
\text{Calculate new \enspace}n(r)=\smash{\sum_i^N}|\psi_i|^2 \\
\Big\downarrow \\
\text{Does the calculation converge?}\pnode[3em, 0pt]{Conv} \\
\Big. \vrule \\
\textbf{\color{green}YES} \\
\Big\downarrow \\
\text{Calculate eigenvalues}
 \end{gathered}
 &\hspace{4em} & \begin{gathered}
 \rnode{Gen}{\text{Generate new\enspace} n(r)} \\
\Big\uparrow \\
\rnode{No}{\textbf{\color{red}NO}}
 \end{gathered}
 \psset{linewidth=0.4pt, nodesep=3pt, arrowinset=0.2, arrowsize=3pt}
 \nccurve[angleA=5, angleB=-100]{Conv}{No}
 \nccurve[angleA=100, angleB=-5, arrows=->]{Gen}{Int}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]